# BigQuery Point Geometry display in Superset

Tags: google-bigquery, geojson, apache-superset

I have a table with latitude and longitude and I want to be able to display it on the Deck.gl chart that accepts geojson

I have a view in BigQuery that returns a geojson object (in a single column) that looks like this -

```
{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [122.80112, 10.004489] }
```

That is valid geojson. I created it in BigQuery by using this function.

```
ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_GeogPoint(longitude, latitude)) as geojson
```

Any ideas on how to make my data display in the Deck.gl 3D Hexagon or Deck.gl Grid charts?

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable with Deck.gl, but upon checking their [python example for Hexagon](https://pydeck.gl/gallery/hexagon_layer.html). It could accept a data frame or csv data. So I think if you use the BQ API to get the JSON data you can try and pass it as dataframe.

Comment: BigQuery GeoViz is the tool BigQuery offers to visualize geospatial data. It uses deck.gl and shows data directly from BiqQuery table. While it does not have hex/grid charts, it might be a useful starting point. The source code is https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-geo-viz


  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-visualize#geo_viz